# Regexp to filter a table

Tags: php, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, codeigniter

ok well i have a table that gets outputted by some open source software but it does not get outputted in an actual table format eg

```
<table> 
  <thead>
     <td>Heading</td>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table
```

Instead The people that developed the software decided that it would be a good a idea to output the table like so

```
+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+
| HEADING 1  | HEADING 2   | ETC   | ANOTHER     | HEADING3   | HEADING4     | SML |
+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+------------+--------------+----------+
| TOTALS        AGENTS:21  |  total|        total|       total|         total| total|
+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+------------+--------------+----------+
```

So i cant build a web scraper to get the Data or well im not shure if i could build a scraper to scrape that  since its all wrapped inside one `<pre> </pre>` tag . So instead i have been trying to use ruby and Regex to try and get the job done so far i have managed to get all the leading `|`'s out and also i have managed to get the heading `+-------+-----` But only that far since it seems that  i have to Repeat the pattern the whole time it doesnt want to repeat itself ok But enough talking for now Here is the Code i have used so far

```
text.lines.to_a.each do |line|
   line.sub(/^\| |^\+*-*\+*\-*/) do |match|
    puts "Regexp Match: " << match
end
STDIN.getc
puts "New Line "<< line
end
```

and for example the output for the first line would only be `+-----------------+----------`
it has be in CSV format so il use `Gsub` to replace the remaining `|`'s with `,`'s

I can use PHP or Ruby so any answer is more than welcome

Comment: Use HTML parser to pickout the text inside `pre` tag, then use substring to extract the data (I assume the columns are at fixed position). If the width of columns are fixed in one table, but not in a different table, then you can analyze the header to figure out the width of each column.

Comment: Here is an example of how the report looks http://s7.postimage.org/gicwtx9xn/vicidial.png currently

Comment: @nhahtdh the columns arnt fixed width by the way i wish they were ahhhh the joys of working with half done code -.-

Comment: Will `|` appear in the content? You can split by `|` if `|` doesn't appear in the content. By fixed width, I mean the width of each column is fixed (different column may have different width, but all rows for a column must have the same width).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete solution in ruby. You need to manually add a `|` to the last line, though.

```
require 'builder'

table = '+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+
| HEADING 1  | HEADING 2   | ETC   | ANOTHER     | HEADING3   | HEADING4     | SML |
+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+------------+--------------+----------+
| TOTALS        AGENTS:21  |  total|        total|       total|         total| total|
+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+------------+--------------+----------+';

def parse_table(table)
  rows = []
  table.each_line do |line|
    next if line.match /^\+/
    rows << line.split(/\s*\|\s*/).reject(&:empty?) 
  end
  rows
end

def html_row(xml, columns)
  xml.tr do
    columns.each do |column|
      xml.td column
    end
  end
end

def html_table(rows)
  head_row = rows.first
  body_rows = rows[1..-1]

  xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new :indent => 2
  xml.table do
    xml.thead do
      html_row xml, head_row
    end
    xml.tbody do
      body_rows.each do |body_row|
        html_row xml, body_row
      end
    end
  end.to_s
end


rows = parse_table(table)
html = html_table(rows)
puts html
```

Output:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>HEADING 1</td>
      <td>HEADING 2</td>
      <td>ETC</td>
      <td>ANOTHER</td>
      <td>HEADING3</td>
      <td>HEADING4</td>
      <td>SML</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>more content</td>
      <td>cont</td>
      <td>More more</td>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>content 2.0</td>
      <td>litl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>more content</td>
      <td>cont</td>
      <td>More more</td>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>content 2.0</td>
      <td>litl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>more content</td>
      <td>cont</td>
      <td>More more</td>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>content 2.0</td>
      <td>litl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>more content</td>
      <td>cont</td>
      <td>More more</td>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>content 2.0</td>
      <td>litl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>more content</td>
      <td>cont</td>
      <td>More more</td>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>content 2.0</td>
      <td>litl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>more content</td>
      <td>cont</td>
      <td>More more</td>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>content 2.0</td>
      <td>litl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>more content</td>
      <td>cont</td>
      <td>More more</td>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>content 2.0</td>
      <td>litl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>more content</td>
      <td>cont</td>
      <td>More more</td>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>content 2.0</td>
      <td>litl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TOTALS        AGENTS:21</td>
      <td>total</td>
      <td>total</td>
      <td>total</td>
      <td>total</td>
      <td>total</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @paddle Wow awesome and then i would just have to build like a mini scraper to get the data out of the local file for exporting to CSV ? or are there Gems for that ?

Comment: So your desired output would be CSV?

Comment: Have a look into the csv class in the ruby std lib

Comment: @paddle yea looked into it shot for the help was first using fastercsv but it seems the it is depreciated ?

Answer (score 3):

this may not be as clean as is could be but it works for this example :)
Ruby:

```
@text = <<END
+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+
| HEADING 1  | HEADING 2   | ETC   | ANOTHER     | HEADING3   | HEADING4     | SML |
+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+------------+--------------+----------+
| TOTALS        AGENTS:21  |  total|        total|       total|         total| total|
+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+------------+--------------+----------+
END
s = @text.scan(/^[|]\W(.*)[|]$/)
puts s
arr = []
arr2 = []
s.each do |o|
  a = o.to_s.split('|')
    a.each do |oo|
      arr2 << oo.to_s.gsub('["','').gsub('"]','').gsub(/\s+/, "")
    end
    arr << arr2
  arr2 = []
end
arr.each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out:

```
$table = '+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+
| HEADING 1  | HEADING 2   | ETC   | ANOTHER     | HEADING3   | HEADING4     | SML |
+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
| content   | more content | cont  | More more   | content    | content 2.0  | litl |
+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+------------+--------------+----------+
| TOTALS        AGENTS:21  |  total|        total|       total|         total| total|
+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+------------+--------------+----------+';

$lines = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $table);
$array = array();
foreach($lines as $line){
  if(!preg_match('/\+-+\+/', $line)){
    $array[] = preg_split('/\s*\|\s*/', trim($line, '| '));
  }
}

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => HEADING 1
            [1] => HEADING 2
            [2] => ETC
            [3] => ANOTHER
            [4] => HEADING3
            [5] => HEADING4
            [6] => SML
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => content
            [1] => more content
            [2] => cont
            [3] => More more
            [4] => content
            [5] => content 2.0
            [6] => litl
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => content
            [1] => more content
            [2] => cont
            [3] => More more
            [4] => content
            [5] => content 2.0
            [6] => litl
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => content
            [1] => more content
            [2] => cont
            [3] => More more
            [4] => content
            [5] => content 2.0
            [6] => litl
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => content
            [1] => more content
            [2] => cont
            [3] => More more
            [4] => content
            [5] => content 2.0
            [6] => litl
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => content
            [1] => more content
            [2] => cont
            [3] => More more
            [4] => content
            [5] => content 2.0
            [6] => litl
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => content
            [1] => more content
            [2] => cont
            [3] => More more
            [4] => content
            [5] => content 2.0
            [6] => litl
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => content
            [1] => more content
            [2] => cont
            [3] => More more
            [4] => content
            [5] => content 2.0
            [6] => litl
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => content
            [1] => more content
            [2] => cont
            [3] => More more
            [4] => content
            [5] => content 2.0
            [6] => litl
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => TOTALS        AGENTS:21
            [1] => total
            [2] => total
            [3] => total
            [4] => total
            [5] => total
        )

)
```

Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: What's with all the global variables? What's the point of using them here?

Answer (score 0):

For the main job of getting the fields out of the table, use `split` with a pattern to get each line:

```
line.split(/\s*\|\s*/)
```

This will split the line into an array based on each `|` and any surrounding whitespace.  Discard the first and last elements of the array, since the pattern also matches the beginning and ending `|`.